# Counterexample for the monotone convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Do you have a counterexample for the monotone convergence theorem when you omit the hypothesis that the sequence is increasing?
I was thinking about the example where the sequence $f_n$ would approach $f$ as $\frac {\sin(x)} x$ do towards $0$. It appears that the integrals are equal, isn't it?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem

Comment: and that the function is strictly positive, I ve understood that without this condition it does not work

Comment: I suspect there may be more than one monotone convergence theorem (I use it for saying that an increasing bounded sequence has a limit which is its supremum)

Comment: Well here we are talking about measure and integration. This theorem comes with Fatou's Lemma and Dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\boldsymbol 1_{[0,n]}$. You have that $$\lim_{n\to \infty }f_n(x)=0,$$ but $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{\mathbb R} f_n=1.$$

Comment: there isn't ? can you detail a little bit please ? this function isn't integrable with lebesgue measure ? (I haven't yet integrate / compute anything with this new integral for me. I'm for now only doing the theory)

Comment: The problem it's $x\mapsto \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is not Lebesgue integral on $\mathbb R$ (even if it's Riemann integrable). Now, if a sequence $(f_n)$ is Cauchy sequence in $L^1$, then it's limit is in $L^1$. Therefore, there are no sequence $(f_n)$ that converges to $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ in $L^1$. @MarineGalantin

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain to a neophyte as I am.